# How to split content from markdown file in jekyll

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll

I'm trying to split some content from my markdown file.

For example my HTML Code looks like

```
<body>
<div class="1">{{ x }}</div>
<div class="2">{{ y }}</div>
<div class="2">{{ y }}</div>
</body>
```

and my markdown file looks like

```
---
layout: subpage
title: ABC
---

<!-- this content should be in div class = 1 --> 
# Hello
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.


<!-- this content should be in div class = 2 --> 
## Bye
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
```

How can I solve this problem? Could you guys please help me? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to split it? For columns? Why don't you put some of it in the YAML?

Answer (score 1):

Put your content in front matter:

```
--- 
layout: subpage 
title: ABC 
p1: this is my first paragraph
p2: this is another one
---
```

Then you can access with `page.p1`:

```
<div>{{page.p1}}</div>
<div>{{page.p2}}</div>
```

Or put them in a list and iterate , you get the idea.